# Beta testing and in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, beta-testing

We are using TestFlight for beta testing and we have an IAP store in our app.

Will the Beta Testers be able to buy the packages from the sandbox environment?

How can we test this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Beta Testers have a proper development provisioning profile installed on their device, then yes.

For development versions of the app, the app will run in the Sandbox environment for IAPS, Game Center,.. and the beta testers will be able to buy the in-app purchase by logging in as a test user associated with the iTunes Connect account(which you need to create first under the "Users - Test Users" tab within iTunes Connect).

Comment: ...or they can use their real account for the testing with real money. :)

Comment: Thanks, but that means that I have to create 100 test accounts for the beta testing?

Comment: if you want to test with 100 accounts, then sure you need to create 100 test accounts. I believe with 15 you're more than ok.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if their main app store ID is what is tied to their beta test account, and they purchase the IAP from the Sandbox with that ID, what happens when the app is released and they go off beta? Do they still have access to the IAP content?

Comment: So can they actually spend real money? It says this on developer.apple.com "If a beta app has In-App Purchases, you do not have to purchase them, as In-App Purchases made with beta builds are free within the context of the beta version."