# Beta testing of in-app purchasing without testers having to spend own $$$?

Tags: ios, app-store, beta-testing

I would like to recruit beta testers for an iOS app as part of the general procedure described [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/beta-test-tutorial-how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app).

Is it correct to assume that beta testing occurs strictly outside the development sandbox environment and hence beta testers have to use their own Apple IDs to test in-app purchases, etc? Since I cannot really expect them to shell out their own $$$ for my testing, is there a proven way forward?

Comment: @rdurand thx for the link. I was not aware of this close duplicate. Am I supposed to delete this question now?

Comment: as you can see, your question was closed when enough people confirmed it was a duplicate. No big deal ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can setup test users in iTunes Connect that allow your users to make purchases in the "sandbox."  This goes through all the IAP lifecycle without actually charging the user.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

I've found that it's useful to setup test users with an existing email address but just adding "+iaptest" before the @ in the email.  For example, with my `test@example.com` I'd use `test+iaptest@example.com`.  Mailers typically ignore what appears after the + and before the @ and then deliver to the remaining email address.  This obviates having to create a new email account just for testing.

In order to use the test account, the user must log out of their current iTunes account by going into `Settings -> iTunes & App Store`, then tap on the existing ID and "Sign Out."  Then start your app and attempt to make a purchase.  THEN log into the test account when prompted.  If you try logging into the test account from `Settings -> iTunes & App Store` it doesn't work.

Comment: So it appears (also from the [linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025847/beta-testing-and-in-app-purchase) question) that beta testers will run the app also in the sandbox environment. I'll give it  a try then.